# Vários botões (JButton) com a mesma função em JPanels diferentes

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

Estou fazendo um programa (utilizando o GUI Builder do NetBeans e CardLayout) com várias telas (vários JPanels) e todas elas terão um botão ínicio, que, obviamente, retorna para tela inicial.

Quero deixar o código mais limpo, então criei uma nova classe, botoes.java (já planejando utiliza-la para outros botões que devem se repetir), e um método:

```
static void inicio(){
    CardLayout c1 = (CardLayout) root.getLayout();
    c1.show(root, "pInicio");
}
```

Quando mando o botão executar este método, funciona normalmente, conforme eu esperava, mas o netbeans indica um erro que está me incomodando: *"root has private access in TelaPrincipal"*, aonde root é o JPanel principal (ou pai) e TelaPrincipal é o JFrame.

Como resolvo isso?

EDIT:

Parte do código da TelaPrincipal:

```
root = new javax.swing.JPanel();
pInicio = new javax.swing.JPanel();
bInicio1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

root.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

root.add(pInicio, "pInicio");

private void bInicioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        Botoes.inicio();
}
```

Comment: Tem como incluir o código da `TelaPrincipal`?

Comment: Como estou usando o GUI Builder do NetBeans, o código completo da TelaPrincipal tem mais de 300 linhas (gerado automáticamente, contém muita formatação e design só), mas tentei filtrar a parte importante / que se relaciona ao problema, editei a pergunta e adicionei ela.

Comment: `root = new javax.swing.` "root" é qual objeto?

Comment: Opa! Mil desculpas! Acabei copiando errado o código, já corrigi! É um JPanel...

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser meio tarde, mesmo assim talvez ajude outra pessoa.
Quando você gera a interface utilizando o GUI Builder do Netbeans, os componentes são gerados com acesso privado na classe, ou seja, não é possível referenciar este objeto a partir de outra classe.
Para resolver este problema, aba as propriedades do componente `root` (seu JPanel) e, na aba `Código` procure por `Modificadores de Variável` (Variable Modifiers) e troque o valor deste campo para `public`.
Deste modo, o componente `root` poderá ser acessado e modificado de qualquer classe.